# Using PHP to Parse complex XML

Tags: php, xml

I need to parse a big XML file, to import some information in to a db, but I'm having troubles accessing all the data inside the XML.

My XML file is something like this:

http://pastebin.com/BzZx0D06

If I do this:

```
print_r($xml);
```

I obtain something like:

http://pastebin.com/3AgSryDZ

For every record I'd like to access to the name attribute of card tag, and to the name tag below (italian traslation).

To access the name attribute I can use:

```
echo (string)$xml->card[0]->attributes()->name;
```

That Works, but I can't find a way to access to the translated name.

For Example, for the first element I have:

```
echo (string)$xml->card[0]->attributes()->name;
```

that return

```
A Display of My Dark Power
```

But I can't find the way to get the "Uno Sfoggio del Mio Potere Oscuro" Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can access the translation like this:

`echo (string)$xml->card[0]->set->name`

Comment: I think I must sleep more than 2hr per night... Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: You are welcome. Next time, just leave the script alone for two hours and do something completely different :)